# How to access a pickled model file saved in desktop to Jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, upickle

I have a pickled model file on my desktop on Mac. I want to load it to my Jupyter notebook. However, when I try this code:

```
import pickle
file_1 = open('RFonevsrest2_model.sav', 'r')
loaded_model = pickle.load(file_1)
```

I get an error saying there is No such file or directory. I do not know how to get the file inside my working directory or access is from local.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the path where the model resides and then using Joblib to access it does the trick:

`RFmodel=open("/Users/sayontimondal/Desktop/RFonevsrest2_model.sav")
loaded_model = joblib.load(RFmodel)`